# Qt: change color part of text

Tags: qt

This is my code:

```
QTextCursor cursor = ui->editor->textCursor(); // editor is QTextEdit
cursor.select(QTextCursor::WordUnderCursor);
QString c = cursor.selectedText();

if (c == keywords[i])
{
    cursor.removeSelectedText();
    cursor.insertHtml("<font color=\"DeepPink\">" + keywords[i] + "</font>");
}
```

So, if the keyword is "new", this word is colored pink. The problem is that everything that is inserted after "new" is also colored red, and not the standard black.
Anybody? :)

UPDATE:

Stupid me. Just added `ui->editor->setTextColor("#000000");`

Comment: You should answer your question and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ui->editor->setTextColor("#000000");
```